# Spring Batch Integration job-launching-gateway

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I am working on simple project that will lunch a job when a new file is created in specific folder but i don't want to use xml only java annotation , so my question is how can i implement the below in code

```
<batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>

<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>
```

BR
Shahbour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl); in your case, you would use

```
...
.handle(jobLauncher())
.handle(logger())
...
```

Where `jobLauncher()` is a `JobLaunchingGateway` `@Bean` and `logger()` is a `LoggingHandler` `@Bean`.

Or use...

```
@ServiceActivator(...)
@Bean
public JobLaunchingGateway jlg() {...}
```

etc., in that case, you need to wire in the output channel to the gateway, which is not needed in the DSL.

Comment: Thanks for the update , just one more question what is the difference between JobLaunchingGateway and JobLaunchingMessageHandler as before reading your answer i tested it with JobLaunchingMessageHandler and it worked ?

Comment: See their source code and JavaDocs: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-integration/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/launch. `JobLaunchingGateway` is an implementation of SI `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` and `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` is just a POJO with an appropriate method to be invoked from SI, e.g. DSL's `.handle()` EIP-method

Comment: I think it is silly question but how can we assign a channel to the LoggingHandler

Comment: Please explain further what you mean (and show your current configuration).